# Android how do they match sms conversations with contact book?

Tags: android

On a Samsung Galaxy, these are the columns associated with the last sms conversation (`content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true`)

```
_id -> 45
date -> 1393156771994
message_count -> 63
recipient_ids -> 46
snippet -> hey what's up
snippet_cs -> 0
read -> 1
type -> 0
error -> 0
has_attachment -> 1
unread_count -> 0
alert_expired -> 1
reply_all -> -1
group_snippet -> null
message_type -> 0
display_recipient_ids -> 46
```

These are the columns associated with the name of my contact in `Phone.CONTENT_URI`

```
_id -> 396
data1 -> +33... (phone number)
data1 -> +33... (phone number)
data2 -> 2
data3 -> null
data4 -> +33... (phone number)
data1 -> +33... (phone number)
data5 -> null
data6 -> null
data7 -> null
data8 -> null
data9 -> null
data10 -> null
data11 -> null
data12 -> null
data13 -> null
data14 -> null
data15 -> null
display_name -> Thomas XXX
display_name_alt -> XXX, Thomas
display_name -> Thomas XXX
display_name_source -> 40
data4 -> +33... (phone number)
data1 -> +33... (phone number)
raw_contact_id -> 56
contact_id -> 407
```

So... I don't see the number 46 here ? How do they match the sms conversation with the contact id ?
Or in other words given the sms thread, how do I retrieve the contact name ?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like it is done by matching address (email or phone number)
This section of the Android code may help, althoughI'm not familiar enough with the MMS/SMS subsystem to promise it will:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/+/refs/heads/tools_r22/src/com/android/providers/telephony/MmsSmsProvider.java

Comment: that's what Im doing, Im just afraid of phone numbers (+1 876 543 210 or +1.876.543.210 or 1876543210...)